# Adjust Margins of a Page on Multiple Pages

Tags: margins, longtable, adjustwidth

I want to adjust the margins of a table on multiple pages. I tried using `\adjustwidth{left margin}{right margin}` using `changepage` package, however, probably this only works if text is to be adjusted on the same page and not in case of multiple pages. The options of `newgeometry` and `restoregemoetry` results in a page break. I don't want to break the page and adjust the margins of the table that is extended to multiple pages.

Comment: if you are using longtable just set LTleft and LTright to set your desired margins

Comment: IIRC, \adjustwidth actually uses \leftskip and \rightskip to overlap the margins.  It should last until something else changes \leftskip and/or \rightskip (which happens a lot).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill standard text width\dotfill X

\bigskip

\noindent X\dotfill 52pt overfull\dotfill X

\begin{longtable}{|ccc|}
  one two three & four five six & seven eight nine\\
  1111111111 1111111111111111111111111& 22 2222 2222 2222 222222 & 33
\end{longtable}


\bigskip

\noindent X\dotfill allowed to extend 1cm into each margin\dotfill X

\setlength\LTleft {-1cm plus 1fill}
\setlength\LTright{-1cm plus 1fill}
\begin{longtable}{|ccc|}
  one two three & four five six & seven eight nine\\
  1111111111 1111111111111111111111111& 22 2222 2222 2222 222222 & 33
\end{longtable}

\bigskip

\noindent X\dotfill standard text width\dotfill X

\end{document}
```